# External hard disk is showing more space than it should

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, disk-space

I have a Seagate external hard disk. Out of sudden it is not detected on all the laptops.

I tried to use disk management, it came up as unknown and not initialized. I tried to initialize it to GPT but it shows incorrect function.

The weird part is that my 1 TB Seagate external is showing 134217728.00 GB unallocated.

I already tried to wipe data, partition recovery with application such as partition master. But all showing so big size even after I waited for more than 1 day the process still stuck at 1%.

What can I do to fix it?

I already took it out from the case. Change it to new USB SATA adapter. Previously before changing, disk management is having hard time to detect the external hard disk. It took some time after plugging before showing up in disk management. But only as not initiate and unknown. No space capacity was shown. I couldn't initiate the drive during that time. It doesnt show up in cmd prompt diskpart as well.

After changing to new USB SATA adapter, it shows up in disk management as in the picture below and show in cmd prompt diskpart as well but still inaccessible. Tried initiate to GPT but it shows incorrect function.

[image: Disk Management window]

Comment: I think it's time to get a new disk.

Comment: It's probably broken, but just in case please provide a screenshot of Disk Management (or any other partition editor).

Comment: I am not sure how to add the picture in comment. I edited the post and add the screenshot via imgur.com

Comment: (1) You wrote "I already tried to wipe data", but one of the tags you used is [tag:data-recovery]. Wiping means no recovery at all. It may be there's nothing you can do, still the question should be consistent. Do you want to recover anything? or just make the drive usable? (2) The external drive may be a regular SATA HDD in a case that translates to and from USB. Have you tried anything to rule out the possibility it's the case that failed? (e.g. taking the disk out, connecting directly via SATA; or using another case or adapter).

Comment: I want to make the external hard drive usable. I need to access the data in it as well. I already tried to recover it with application before wiping the data yet I couldn't recover a thing since it is not accessible. So i got desperate. I tried wiping the data thinking i could access it after wiping the data and then only recover the data after it become accessible. Yet I cant even wipe the data. This is the result after i took it out from the casing and change it to new USB SATA adapter. Previously it is hard to detect by disk management. Only showing unknown and no initiated.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that must be the world’s largest hard drive. ;-)

134,217,728 GiB translates to exactly 2<sup>48</sup> 512-byte sectors. Coincidentally, with LBA48, you can address at most 2<sup>48</sup>-1 sectors, so it’s probably actually 134,217,728 GiB minus 512 byte, which is then rounded up.

Either way, this means the hard drive identifies in a terribly incorrect way. Since you mention that this is an external hard drive, chances are very high it’s not actually the hard drive that is broken but rather the USB-SATA interface. You should remove it from the external enclosure and either put it inside a new one or mount it internally in a PC.

Once you have tested in inside a new enclosure or in a PC, you’ll know whether the actual hard drive can be salvaged. You’ll also be able to perform data recovery – whatever may be left after the wipe attempt.

---

Wiping a drive that looks like this serves no useful purpose. At best it may destroy the data, while fixing nothing anyway. In the future, you should refrain from doing this, especially when hoping to recover data.

---

Update: You indicate in comments that the state we see is already with a different USB-SATA adapter. This strongly hints at the hard drive itself being dead. With luck, your wipe attempts were not written to the drive. You can try a data recovery service, for a price. Some may offer a plan where they don’t charge if recovery is entirely impossible.

Comment: I see.. man got desperate.. =( i already tried taking it out from the seagate case. This is the result after plugging it with new USB-SATA adapter. Previously disk management cant read it at all. Just showing not initiate and unknown and it doesnt show the space capacity at all. No size, no unallocated. Just blank. Should i get another adapter to access it? Thank you for the advice though. Will try not to next time. Hopefully there wont be next time. ='(

Comment: Alright, so the hard drive itself is toast. Any further recovery attempts should be performed by professionals—if you feel that’s worth it. Because it won’t be cheap.

Comment: I see.. there's nothing can be done by me anymore eh.. =( okay.. thank you for the advice..